# Python: To get proper attribute / function name for dynamically added functions

Tags: python

Below is the sample code.

```
import inspect
from types import MethodType
class Settings(object):
    APPS = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
    def __init__(self):
        Settings._setup_apps(self)

    @classmethod
    def _setup_apps(cls, instance):

        def _setup(self, appname = None):
            print "appname : ", appname
            print "inspect : ", inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

        for app in Settings.APPS:
            new_attr_name = _setup.__name__[1:] + '_' + app
            setattr(Settings, new_attr_name, _setup)
            # setattr(instance, new_attr_name, MethodType(_setup, instance, type(instance)))
```

Execution

```
s = Settings()
s.setup_s1()
```

Result

```
appname :  None
inspect :  _setup
```

How can I get the app name 's1' to be available in the function 'setup_s1' (similarly 's2' & 's3' in 'setup_s2' & 'setup_s3' respectively), with out passing the 'appname' explicitly while calling. i.e

```
s.setup_s1('s1') # Do not prefer this
```

But updating the default value of 'appname' from 'None' to 's1' / 's2' / 's3' during the creation of attribute 'setup_s1' / 'setup_s2' / 'setup_s3' is good. (I don't know if this is possible).

Comment: Why do you have the `_setup` method inside your `_setup_apps` class method?

Comment: Just to keep all code at one place here, I did it. You can even place the `_setup` function outside of the class `Settings`, the result will still be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to bind parameters to a function:

```
import inspect
import functools

class Settings(object):
    APPS = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
    def __init__(self):
        Settings._setup_apps(self)

    @classmethod
    def _setup_apps(cls, instance):

        def _setup(self, appname = None):
            print "appname : ", appname
            print "inspect : ", inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

        for app in Settings.APPS:
            new_attr_name = _setup.__name__[1:] + '_' + app
            setattr(Settings, new_attr_name, functools.partial(_setup, instance, app))
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for `appname`. Do you have any inputs on the function name ? It is still `_setup`.